# Weirdness in Perl Net::SMTP

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I'm having some trouble with Net::SMTP when used in a for loop.
The first iteration works, but on the second iteration the script dies with Can't call method "mail" on an undefined value at..., the line referred to being

```
$smtp->mail('hacker@hacker.net'); #from.
```

Any ideas?! Thanks for your time!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP;

my $smtp;

#@data is defined and populated somewhere

foreach my $line (@data) {

  my @linearray = split /,/, $line;
  my $host = $linearray[2];

  $host =~ s/\r|\n//g;

  next unless ($host =~  m/([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})/); # skip if it's not an IP (i.e. it's the header row)
  print "Connecting to $host...";

  # create object
  $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
    Hello => 'hacker.net',
    Timeout => 3,
    Host => $host,
    Debug => 1,
  );
  $smtp->mail('hacker@hacker.net'); #from
  my $tocheck = $smtp->recipient('my_email@sanitised.com'); #to
  if ($tocheck == 0) {
    print "$host is NOT an open relay\n";
    #$smtp->quit;
    next;
  }

  $smtp->data();
  $smtp->datasend("Test\n");
  $smtp->datasend("\n");
  $smtp->datasend("A simple test message\n");
  $smtp->dataend();
  $smtp->quit;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: I think there's a typo in the IP-matching line, in the part of the regex for the last tuple: `[0-+9]` should be `[0-9]`. Also, the preceding delimiter dot isn't escaped.

Comment: What's the second host you are connecting to?  If you take out the second line, does it work?  You should check the return value from `Net::SMTP::new()` anyway.

Comment: Tanks zb226 - don't know how that typo crept in there

Comment: All IPs are valid and have been checked beforehand. The issue seems to be in the looping. If I replicate the #create object block and set $host to unique fixed values at each instance, it works. Alternatively, if I tweak the script so that it reads from the array for the first and third+ iteration, but manually set the value of $host for the second iteration, it fails on the third. Same happens if I manually set, say, the fifth iteration (i.e. it's not an issue with a particular element of the array).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your `$host` doesn't hold a valid SMTP server address. The regex checks only whether it *contains* something that may be a valid IP address somewhere. `999.999.999.999` isn't valid, for instance. Also whitespace will probably break things, so `' 127.0.0.1    '` won't work either. Finally there may be no working SMTP server at that address, even if it is a legal IP address so your contructor may fail anyway.

This alternative regex checks that the *entire string* matches a valid IP address with only 0..255 values in each field.

```
/\A(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\z/
```

You should check the return value of the constructor and warn if it has failed:

```
$smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
  Hello => 'hacker.net',
  Timeout => 3,
  Host => $host,
  Debug => 1,
);
unless ($smtp) {
  warn "Unable to connect to to SMTP server '$host'";
  next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Tail slightly between the legs on this one. It turns out that the list of IPs given to me had already been contacted about the issue and therefore some has started putting measures in place to fix the problem. One such measure was blocking TCP port 25 with a source IP different to a trusted relay (not my IP just to clarify). Therefore creation of the Net::SMTP was simply failing. So reintroduction of the block suggested by Borodin (which I'd removed while trying to debug this issue) fixed it all up. Thanks for your help guys - much appreciated.